# Flagging as Too Broad shows as both Too Broad and Duplicate in Flag Dialog

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, flags

I recently flagged a question as "Too Broad", and out of curiosity, clicked the flag button again (I had no intention of raising two flags). I was surprised to see the following dialog:

[image: Flag Dialog]

I am 100% sure that I have not raised a duplicate flag on this question. After noticing the flag dialog oddity, I went searching for duplicates and couldn't find any. Is there any reason both flag types would be marked as previously raised due to a "Too Broad" flag?

BTW, I have tagged this question with "Bug" because it fit the "best", but I'm not really trying to file a bug report. I would just like to understand the site behavior better, and I can file a proper bug report later if there isn't a good explanation for this.

Comment: I'm sure Shog's typing up an answer as we speak; but if you want help with understanding site functionality then [support] is an appropriate tag.

Comment: @Ben Thanks. Since Shog9 already added the status-bydesign tag, I won't retag this question, but I'll use the [tag:support] tag next time. I interpreted that as intended more for "how do I do a thing" type questions, but I see that was an incorrect interpretation.

Comment: @hichris123 ...Yup. I noticed that after I already posted this question. Should I just go ahead and delete this to save the mods the effort?

Comment: @ScottLawson You won't be able to delete it as it has an answer, and leaving duplicates makes it easier for people to find the same question. So just go ahead and vote-to-close it as a duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "type" of flag here is "close". That includes Too Broad, Duplicate, Off-topic, Unclear... all flags that suggest the question should be closed.

There are other types of flags, and those aren't disabled - but if you'd selected one of those instead, then all other flags of that type would've appeared disabled when you reopened the dialog.

Comment: Hint hint: This is confusing.

Comment: Perhaps it should not say "you have already raised this type of flag", but name the type: "You already flagged for closing."