# Flag Dialog shows that I have already raised some flags but not others, but I am disallowed from raising any types of flags

Tags: support, flags, flag-dialog

Before I start, this is not a duplicate of questions like [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271326/flagging-as-too-broad-shows-as-both-too-broad-and-duplicate-in-flag-dialog), as those are referring to it appearing that they flagged twice but they only did it once.

My issue is that while the flag dialog shows that I have used one type of flag and thus denies use of that one, I actually am unable to use *any* of the options to flag.

> [image: Flag dialog, Spam and Offensive labeled as already raised, clearly spam answer in the background]

> [image: Result from trying to flag a second time (EG "not an answer"): Red error "You have already flagged this post for moderator attention"]

This is contrary to what the dialog implies.

Either deny loading the dialog again with the error message *when the flag button is first clicked*, or allow flagging of multiple types.  (Note: I believe that in the past flagging multiple types worked)

Note that while the question I included above was not the perfect sample as it was definite spam and no other flags are really necessary, there are other samples where both a "Not an answer" flag and a custom flag are needed.  In the past I flagged them both ways and it worked, but now it does not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That message has nothing to do with the types of flags you've cast in the past. You are only allowed to have one *active* flag on a post at any given time, no matter what types of flags you've used in the past, and *that* is what that error message is actually saying. Once your previous flag gets handled on a post, you will be able to flag it again with other options which are not disabled.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense.  The message could be clearer about that, though.  (Something like "You already have one active flag on this post; please wait until a moderator processes the current one")

Comment: Since when is it restricted to a single active flag per post? I mean, it totally makes sense to flag SPAM/offensive, and then decide to better add some details with an "other"-flag. Or to upgrade from flagging NAA/VLQ to Spam. Or flagging for closure, and also adding an "other"-flag for migration to some other site.